# Adding a progress bar to my process with tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have my process working with Tkinter, but when I run my code my program freeze I understandt It´s because of the main loop, I have been reading the documentation of Tkinter and reading some other questions but I can´t really understand how to implement the Progress Bar to my process, my code It´s really simple it just dowload some information and then save It like an excel but It takes some time to do the process, so how can I implement the progress bar here.

```
root=Tk()
root.title('Info Dowload')
root.iconbitmap('Logo.ico')
root['bg'] = '#E1FAF9'
#VariablesInicio
fecha1=Entry(root)
fecha2=Entry(root)
date1.insert(0, "ejm:2022-03-15")
date2.insert(0, "ejm:2022-03-15")
#Label
label1=Label(root,text="First Date(aaaa-mm-dd):",font=('Bahnschrift',11))
label2=Label(root,text="Second date(aaaa-mm-dd):",font=('Bahnschrift',11))

def Click():
    
    boton1.config(state= "disable")
    label3=Label(root,text="Working with: "+date1.get())
    label4=Label(root,text="Working with: "+date2.get())
    label3.grid(row=3,column=0)
    label4.grid(row=4,column=0)
    startFac=str(date1.get())+' 00:00:00' 
    endFac=str(date2.get())+' 23:59:59'
    
    ##First Query
    startMF=str(date1.get()) 
    endMF=str(date2.get())
    startMF=startMF.replace('-','/') 
    endMF=endMF.replace('-','/') 
   
    df=query1(startMF, endMF)
    df1=query2(startFac, endFac, df)
    sales=pd.merge(left=df,right=df1,how='left',on=['code1','code2','code3'])    
    sales.to_excel('sales.xlsx',index=None)
    

#Button
import tkinter as tk   
boton1=tk.Button(root,text='Ejecutar',bg='#20bebe',fg='white',height=1,width=6,command=Click)
    #Print info
    label1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    label2.grid(row=1,column=0)
    fecha1.grid(row=0,column=1)
    fecha2.grid(row=1,column=1)
    boton1.grid(row=2,column=0)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to add a progress bar, you can use the Progressbar class as follows:

```
progressbar = Progressbar(root, orient='horizontal',mode='indeterminate',length=<your preferred length>)
```

Additionally, you would also have to define when to start and stop displaying your progress bar. In order to do this, add the `pb.start()` and `pb.stop()` commands at the start and end of your `click()` function respectively.

[**Suggested by @Matiss**]
In order to solve the problem of the progress bar not moving, you can `import threading` module and use it as follows:

```
root=Tk()
root.title('Info Dowload')
root.iconbitmap('Logo.ico')
root['bg'] = '#E1FAF9'
#VariablesInicio
fecha1=Entry(root)
fecha2=Entry(root)
date1.insert(0, "ejm:2022-03-15")
date2.insert(0, "ejm:2022-03-15")
#Label
label1=Label(root,text="First Date(aaaa-mm-dd):",font =('Bahnschrift',11))
label2=Label(root,text="Second date(aaaa-mm-dd):",font =('Bahnschrift',11))

def Click():
    boton1.config(state= "disable")
    label3=Label(root,text="Working with: "+date1.get())
    label4=Label(root,text="Working with: "+date2.get())
    label3.grid(row=3,column=0)
    label4.grid(row=4,column=0)
    progressbar.start()
    t1.start()
    
def download():
    
    startFac=str(date1.get())+' 00:00:00' 
    endFac=str(date2.get())+' 23:59:59'

    ##First Query
    startMF=str(date1.get()) 
    endMF=str(date2.get())
    startMF=startMF.replace('-','/') 
    endMF=endMF.replace('-','/') 

    df=query1(startMF, endMF)
    df1=query2(startFac, endFac, df)
    sales=pd.merge(left=df,right=df1,how='left',on=['code1','code2','code3'])    
    sales.to_excel('sales.xlsx',index=None)
    progressbar.stop()

#Code for multithreading
t1 = threading.Thread(target=download)    

#Code for progress bar
progressbar = Progressbar(root, orient='horizontal',mode='indeterminate',length=<your preferred length>)
progressbar.grid()
```

Comment: I just put it on my code and when I run It, It´s just display the ProgressBar but It won´t move until the program It´s over.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your whole code so that I can try running it on my computer to see what you exactly mean? If you mean that you want to hide the progress bar, then you could use grid_forget() command

Comment: They want to run two processes at the same time which means either using `threading` (mostly this) module or `multiprocessing` module, then putting the downloading part in that separate "place" and sending info from there to `tkinter`'s "place" and updating the widgets there, in this case it is less complex due to the "indeterminate" "flag"

Comment: Yeah, exactly what Matiis said, the code I´m using is the one you see the only difference is that those queries functions are SQL Queries.

Comment: PaulCoder Let me know whether the above code works! Thanks for the suggestion @Matiiss

Comment: it is better now, but in the given code `download` is used before defined as a function, also calling `tkinter` functions from another thread is not suggested, it can potentially crash `tkinter` without warning